# Is there a way to agilize my web scraping?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to complement a Pandas dataframe by scraping data from a website (using BeautifulSoup).

Since this website asks whether I am human, I needed to use a proxy to bypass this - for this I use Scraper API. I organized my code in a loop since I need to do this ~1600 times to acces a specific routes within the website to get the data from:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/'

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    url_date = url + str(row.date)
    payload = {'api_key': 'a_key', 'url': url_date}
    response = requests.get('http://api.scraperapi.com', params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser' )
    df.at[row,'column_name'] = soup.find("div", {"class": "a class"}).get_text(strip=True)[-2:]
```

However, with so many urls to check, this code runs really slow. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am also very new to web scraping I don't exactly know the working of the solution but I hope I can point you to a potential solUtion.

You can use **async/await** or **multithreading** technique to make multiple parallel calls without waiting for the response first.

Code written in an asynchronous fashion enables operations to be executed concurrently, rather than sequentially, resulting in improved performance when making multiple network requests or carrying out other I/O-intensive tasks.

Multithreading is another way to improve the performance of your code. A thread is a separate execution context in a program, and multiple threads can run in parallel on a computer with multiple cores.

Async is ideal for I/O-bound operations like network requests, while threading is better suited for computationally expensive CPU-bound tasks.

To know more about this method you can visit: [This John Watson Web Scraping Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii7x4mpIhIs)

Comment: This looks promising. I will look into it, many thanks!